# Load different api content on click (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, api

I get some data out of an API. The data comes in JSON format.
I fetch the data with PHP and put it out in HTML.

Now what I want to do is, to implement a filter mechanic to output different content from the API.

Example:

I can call the API with a filter. I choose one request with type = 1 and another with type = 2. Both calls return a JSON object with the expected data. I do a foreach loop in PHP and put out the data from call 1. I do another loop with data 2. At the beginning I want to display Data 1 and when I click on a link (e.g. Get data 2) the data 2 should be loaded and replace data 1.

So far so good. I have not much experience with JavaScript or JQuery. What is the right approach? Fetching the data from the API call and work directly with JS? Is there a way to store the PHP output and just load the output that is needed?

I dont have much code to show because this more like setting up a base. I like to understand how to approach these problems and get to a solution by myself (Still learning). Maybe someone can explain the steps to get to a solution.

```
<?php
  // Making an API call with POST as the method.
  // The $filter1 variable holds a JSON Object with search terms for
  // data 1
  $results = new APIReader('POST', 'https://www.linktoapi.com/', $filter1, 'username:password');
?>
<!-- Links to filter the data output -->
<nav>
  <a href="#data1">get data 1</a>
  <a href="#data2">get data 2</a>
</nav>

<?php
  // Loop through data 1
  foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->ID;
  }

?>
```

So I do another API call and loop for data 2. How can I load data 2 instead of data 1 without having to reload the page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Is there a way to store the PHP output and just load the output that is needed?`. Absolutely, you can pass an object with the specs information and filter the data in your PHP code before sending it back to the client. Or if you don't want to do that in PHP, you can create an implementation in `APIReader()` to do that via client-side JS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various ways to do. You can either do it at the client side and as well as at the server side.
It is possible to update the UI without reloading the page and the technique used is "AJAX".

Now it depends on you wheather you want to do it at client side or server side.

For client side:
 1. Call the Api and get the whole data and store it an  global javascript variable ( you can store it in localstorage as well so it does not removed after page refresh).
2. Now you can loop through the data and filter the data as and when required.

For server side:
1. Make 2 Api's at the server with different queries as you required.
2. Now call these Api via Ajax and your page will never get reload but the page will get refreshed.

You should use Jquery for easy implementation.

````
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var dataFetched = null;

  //fetching and storing the data on page load

  $.ajax({url: "https://www.linktoapi.com/", success: function(result){
      dataFetched = result;
    }});


  $("#button1").click(function(){
       if(dataFetched){
           //filter the data and show the result
       }
  });

  $("#button2").click(function(){
      if(dataFetched){
           //filter the data and show the result
       }
  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="button1">API 1</button>

<button id="button2">API 2</button>

</body>
</html> ```
````

Comment: Okay, I want to try the client side approach. For my understanding: I call the API via PHP and now I can store the result of that call in a JavaScript variable?

Comment: You call the php api via javascript and send the response from php api to your javascript.

Comment: I have edited my answer you can check the dummy code idea above.

Comment: But how do i tell the api url which method, authentification and filter? Like in my example.

Comment: You can pass that in ajax request...   ``` var myKeyVals = { A1984 : 1, A9873 : 5, A1674 : 2, A8724 : 1, A3574 : 3, A1165 : 5 }



var saveData = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "someaction.do?action=saveData",
      data: myKeyVals,
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
});```

Answer (score 1):

This (top of mind, quick-and-dirty code) isn't the best way to solve it, although I hope it'll probably help you a step in the right direction

Points of interest:

- Input needs to be sanitized
- $_GET isn't the best way to get input
- urls in href should be well formed

```
<?php

  $filter = GetRequiredFilterObjectFor($_GET['dataId']); // This function you'll have to create

  // Making an API call with POST as the method.
  // The $filter variable holds a JSON Object with search terms for
  // data <dataId querystring parameter>
  $results = new APIReader('POST', 'https://www.linktoapi.com/', $filter, 'username:password');
?>
<!-- Links to filter the data output -->
<nav>
  <a href="?dataId=1">get data 1</a>
  <a href="?dataId=2">get data 2</a>
</nav>

<?php
  // Loop through data
  foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->ID;
  }

?>
```

Comment: I will try this approach also. In the GetRequiredFilterObjectFor method, i just do a quick if statement. If the $_GET data = 1, i use filter1 and if it is 2 i use filter . Right?

Comment: That would probably work :-)